# How to generate different sizes of icons from .psd?

Tags: ios, png, photoshop

iOS app needs different sizes of icons to fit different screens, so after we design an icon with psd format, we will have to generate many icons(29px*29px,40px*40px,...), which is a tedious task.

How to batch generate them at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Actions...
in Actions tab click record and do the task... photoshop will record it and next time you went to do this again just click on "Play" icon

Hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Photoshop CC` you can generate [image assets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html)  from `Layers`.

For example if you set this name to a `Layer`:

```
29px x 29px icon29x29.png, 40px x 40px icon40x40.png, 128px x 128px icon128x128.png
```

Will generates these image assets:

- icon29x29.png
- icon40x40.png
- icon128x128.png

With these specific sizes.